Separ un registro que tiene un rango de fechas a un registro por dia sql
tengo una duda
Tengo un registro ejemplo:



ID
FechaIn
FechaFin




10
2024/06/15
2024/06/18



y no se si sea posible separar ese registro en varias segun sea el rango de fechas:



ID
FechaIn
FechaFin




10
2024/06/15
2024/06/15


10
2024/06/16
2024/06/16


10
2024/06/17
2024/06/17


10
2024/06/18
2024/06/18



Ojala alguien tenga una idea o si es posible

Fecha inicio y fecha fin son iguales en tu segunda tabla. ¿No tendría sentido tener un solo campo ahí, "día" o algo así?

¿Que motor de base de datos usas?

@R_VA_0909 Recuerda aceptar la respuesta si solucionó tu problema, para que otras personas puedan visualizarla y ser ayudadas en problemas semejantes.

Lo que estás pidiendo se llama una subConsulta N, esto lo puedes resolver de la siguiente manera:
SELECT 
    ID, 
    DATE_ADD(FechaIn, INTERVAL n DAY) AS FechaIn, 
    DATE_ADD(FechaIn, INTERVAL n DAY) AS FechaFin
FROM 
    TuTabla,
    (
        SELECT a.N + b.N * 10 + c.N * 100 AS n
        FROM 
            (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL 
             SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a,
            (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL 
             SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b,
            (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL 
             SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) c
    ) n
WHERE 
    DATE_ADD(FechaIn, INTERVAL n.n DAY) <= FechaFin
ORDER BY 
    ID, FechaIn;

Okey ahora te voy a explicar que hace:
En primer lugar esta subConsulta te va a genera una tabla de números del 0 al 999 (10 * 10 * 10) esto lo puedes ajusta dependiendo del rango máximo de fechas que esperes manejar, ya que esto va a crear cada registro.
Ahora Bien tenemos el DATE_ADD el cual te añade días a la fecha FechaIn utilizando el número generado por la subconsulta n.
... y tiene un WHERE el cual te va a filtra las filas para incluir solo aquellas donde la fecha calculada esté dentro del rango de FechaIn a FechaFin.
Este SQL te va a generar un registro para cada día en el rango de fechas para cada registro de la tabla.
IMPORTANTE: Este SQL es para Mysql
Aqui tienes mi prueba que hice para tu ejemplo:
Esta es la tabla

Este es el Resultado del SQL


@R_VA_0909 Recuerda aceptar la respuesta si solucionó tu problema, para que otras personas puedan visualizarla y ser ayudadas en problemas semejantes.
